# Property does not exist on type - but type has this property defined

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to populate a mat-select list with the names of a set of scoring rounds.

Here I define what a scoring round is:

```
scoring.rounds.ts
export interface ScoringRounds {
    id: number; 
    name: string;
    arrowsPerEnd: number;
    numberOfEnds: number;
    distanceOne: string;
    endsOne: number;
    faceOne: string;
    distanceTwo?: string;
    endsTwo?: number;
    faceTwo?: string;
    distanceThree?: string;
    endsThree?: number;
    faceThree?: string;
    distanceFour?: string;
    endsFour?: number;
    faceFour?: string;
    scoreType: string;
}
```

Here I provide a service to retrieve the list of rounds:

```
scoring-rounds.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ScoringRounds } from './scoring.rounds';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ScoringRoundsService {

  protected scoringRoundsList: ScoringRounds[] = [
    {id: 1, name: 'WA50', arrowsPerEnd: 6, numberOfEnds: 12, 
    distanceOne: '50m', endsOne: 12, faceOne: '122cm',
    scoreType: 'Metric 10 Zone'},
    {id: 2, name: 'WA1440', arrowsPerEnd: 6, numberOfEnds: 24, 
    distanceOne: '90m', endsOne: 6, faceOne: '122cm', 
    distanceTwo: '70m', endsTwo: 6, faceTwo: '122cm', 
    distanceThree: '50m', endsThree: 6, faceThree: '80cm',
    distanceFour: '30m', endsFour: 6, faceFour: '80cm',
    scoreType: 'Metric 10 Zone'}

]

getAllScoringRoundNames(): ScoringRounds[] {
  return this.scoringRoundsList.name;
}

}
```

and I receive the following error when adding .name to the return, or when trying to use it in the html to provide the values for mat-select.

> [{
> >>"resource": "/c:/TM470/target-club/src/app/add-scores/add-scores.component.html",
> "owner": "*generated_diagnostic_collection_name*#0",
> "code": "2339",
> "severity": 8,
> "message": "Property 'name' does not exist on type 'ScoringRounds[]'.",
> "source": "ngtsc",
> "startLineNumber": 20,
> "startColumn": 88,
> "endLineNumber": 20,
> "endColumn": 92,
> "relatedInformation": [
> {
> "startLineNumber": 19,
> "startColumn": 8,
> "endLineNumber": 19,
> "endColumn": 37,
> "message": "Error occurs in the template of component AddScoresComponent.",
> "resource": "/c:/TM470/target-club/src/app/add-scores/add-scores.component.ts"
> }
> ]
> }]

I have tried multiple methods but cannot understand why this is saying the property does not exist, when I have explicitly defined it in scoring.rounds.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.scoringRoundsList` is an array of `ScoringRounds`, which does not have the `name` property. If you want to get the `name` for all the `scoringRounds`, try this:

```js
getAllScoringRoundNames(): string[] {
  return this.scoringRoundsList.map(round => round.name);
}
```

In your form, use the markup below. Notice:

- I am binding the round's `name` as the `value` of each `mat-option` - this will make this round get selected on click, instead of the array
- Add it inside the `mat-option` component as well - this displays the name in the dropdown menu that you see

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Round Name</mat-label>
  <mat-select formControlName="roundName" [(ngModel)]="scoringRoundsList">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let round of scoringRoundsList" [value]="round.name">
      {{round.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Refer to the [Angular Material documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview) if you have any further questions.

Comment: Thank you, this did get rid of my errors. However, a follow up question. 
On my form, this is now showing a drop down with two blank options. 
Selecting either inputs an array of both name items. like so: [WA50, WA1440]. 

Here's the relevant from the HTML:
`
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Round Name</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="roundName" [(ngModel)]="scoringRoundsList">
      <mat-option *ngFor = "let round of scoringRoundsList" [value]="scoringRoundsList">
      </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
`